# Adding a geometry to openpyxl worksheet

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm looking for a way to insert shapes into a worksheet created with Openpyxl.

this kind of code doesn't work:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.geometry import Bevel

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
b = Bevel(1,1)
ws.add_chart(b) //or add_image
```

it say : `AttributeError: 'Bevel' object has no attribute 'anchor'` which is true. I cannot found any information on how to deal with shapes with Openpyxl.

Comment: Although the primitives exist it's currently not possible to add shapes. These are done directly in drawings.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentences "These are done directly in drawings". What does this mean ? If I read correctly all doc about python excel lib (openpyxl, xlrd, xlsxwriter) there is no way right now to write a shape in excel file through python ?

Comment: As I said: it's not currently possible.